# How to convert selection sort to the Comparator interface?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, selection-sort

Here is the code for a selection sort function:

```
public class Selection
{
    public static void sort (Comparable [] a)
    { //Sort [] into increasing order.
        int N = a.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {    //Exchange a[i] with the smallest entry in a[i+1...N).
             int min = i;
             for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
                if (less (a[j], a[min]) ) min = j;
             exch(a, i, min); // assume exch has been implemented already
        }
    }
}
```

I was told that to support comparators in sort implementations, all I had to do was use "Object" instead of "Comparable", and to pass "Comparator" to "sort()" and "less()" and to use it in "less)".
Would this be the proper way of making it in the comparator interface? :

```
public class Selection
{
    public static void sort (Object [] a, Comparator c)
    { //Sort [] into increasing order.
        int N = a.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {    //Exchange a[i] with the smallest entry in a[i+1...N).
             int min = i;
             for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
                if (less (c, a[j], a[min]) ) min = j;
             exch(a, i, min); 
        }
    }
}

private static booloean less (Comparator c, Object v, Object w)
{
    return c.compare(v, w) < 0; 
}

private static void exch (Object [] a, int i, int j)
{
    Object swap = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = swap; 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure whoever told you that, didn't actually mean something like this: java.util.Arrays.sort(T[], java.util.Comparator)

Answer (score 0):

What you did there is indeed a way of generalizing the algorithm, so that it does not only work on `Comparable` objects, but on arbitrary objects, by using a `Comparator`. There are some issues with the code (for example, the fact that *raw types* are used), but your change could be described as "the smallest modification that is necessary to achieve the desired goal".